# Please check JNDI Realm Configuration

Tags: java, tomcat, active-directory, ldap, jndi

My Tomcat web application logs are telling me the user1 isn't in the specified mapped LDAP role/group coming from AD. I believe my issues lie with the JNDI Realm definition. Can someone review it please and see where I may be going wrong, I've included the DN information from AD as well:

My "user1" account DN is

```
DistinguishedName : CN=user1,OU=Users,OU=Lab,DC=example,DC=com
```

The role/group "Users" I have specified in the web.xml config is

```
DistinguishedName : CN=Users,CN=Builtin,DC=example,DC=com
```

My Realm configuration is

```
<Realm
className="org.apache.catalina.realm.JNDIRealm"
debug="99"
connectionURL="ldap://example.com:389"
authentication="simple"
referrals="follow"
connectionName="cn=administrator,cn=users,dc=example,dc=com"
connectionPassword="##########"
userSearch="(sAMAccountName={0})"
userBase="cn=users,dc=example,dc=com"
userSubtree="true"
userRoleName="memberOf"
roleSearch="(member={0})"
roleName="cn"
roleSubtree="true"
roleBase="cn=users,cn=builtin,dc=example,dc=com"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Fixed myself. This was the correct configuration.

```
<Realm
 className="org.apache.catalina.realm.JNDIRealm"
 debug="99"
 connectionURL="ldap://example.com:3268"
 authentication="simple"
 referrals="follow"
 connectionName="cn=administrator,cn=users,dc=example,dc=com"
 connectionPassword="########"
 userSearch="(sAMAccountName={0})"
 userBase="dc=example,dc=com"
 userSubtree="true"
 userRoleName="memberOf"
 roleName="cn"
 roleSubtree="true"/>
```